# ios anaylize crash log?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have the following symbolized crash log. Or maybe something I missed?
Help please to understand what does it mean:

OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3591f628 0x3590e000 + 71208

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34accb1a nanosleep + 138

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ad7608 sleep + 40

3   ReportCrash                     0x001046f2 0xfc000 + 34546

4   ReportCrash                     0x000fd474 0xfc000 + 5236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is state of your app at the crash moment, can show you where crash was. In your case app crashed with Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) in thread 0 and you can see stacks of functions of all active threads. If you want convert it to human readable view, you should use special programs like symbolicate , atos or dwarfdump.

More:

http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

http://aplus.rs/ios-dev/guide-to-symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-logs-with-xcode-4-2/

(about atos i have link just in Russian)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you have the archive file in Xcode -> Widow ->Organizer and a corresponding crash log file.

Connect your device to mac

goto Xcode->Window-> devices

Click on your device on the left panel

Click on view device logs

Select the log you want to symbolicate. (OR) If you have a crash log file on your system then click on All logs option on the left panel and drag the log file into left panel section.

Right click on the selected log and click re-symbolicate

Done!!! ,